# Making groups of 2., probability of getting a certain group?

Tags: probability

Let us say we have $n$ people $p_1, ...., p_n$ where $n$ is even. We find some random way to make groups of 2, and we are interested in if $p_i$ gets in a group with $p_j$, if $p_i$ gets $p_k$, $p_j$ gets in a group with $p_k$, and etc. Let us say that we have $m$ 'groups' that we wonder whether they occur. How can we calculate this probability? For example, what's the probability that a group is $(p_1,p_2)$ OR $(p_2,p_3)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague. For the *particular* case of $(p_1,p_2)$ OR $(p_2,p_3)$

$p_2$ can be in any of $n$ slots. Now there are $(n-1)$ slots left, of which $1$ is in $p_2's$ group,

so $Pr = \dfrac1{n-1}$

Similarly, $Pr =\dfrac1{n-1}$ for $p_3$ being with $p_2$.

Add the two to get the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are $n-1$ equally likely ways to choose $p_2$'s partner. Of these, $2$ are "favourable."